# Can someone help me to decode SSL related stack trace?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I have a small HTTPServer with seld-signed certificate. When I send GET request using Chrome, I get security exception as expected. Then during handshaking I get below error:

How to interpret it ? What does version 32 means ? SSL = 3 and TLS = 2 ?

```
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591): Error fetching file from server., Stack Trace : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Error occured in delegated task:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PROTOCOL VERSION. Unsupported client version 32
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.HandshakeProtocol.fatalAlert(HandshakeProtocol.java:319)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.HandshakeProtocol.wrap(HandshakeProtocol.java:271)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:695)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:464)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:1018)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1137)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:814)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:422)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:471)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591): Caused by: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.AlertException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PROTOCOL VERSION. Unsupported client version 32
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.HandshakeProtocol.fatalAlert(HandshakeProtocol.java:308)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ServerHandshakeImpl.processClientHello(ServerHandshakeImpl.java:356)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ServerHandshakeImpl$1.run(ServerHandshakeImpl.java:124)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ServerHandshakeImpl$1.run(ServerHandshakeImpl.java:122)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:182)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.DelegatedTask.run(DelegatedTask.java:52)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.run(SslHandler.java:1258)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:31)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1255)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1140)
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     ... 12 more
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PROTOCOL VERSION. Unsupported client version 32
05-07 10:16:12.510: W/HttpDefaultRequestHandler(26591):     ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 32:

3 => Major version number of the protocol
2 => Minor version number of the protocol (This seems to be equal to 0 for SSLv3 and 1 for TLSv1 and *2 has not been defined* which is why you have the error)

References:

1. Draft - [The SSL Protocol Version 3.0](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft302.txt)
2. SourceCode - [ProtocolVersion.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/org/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse/ProtocolVersion.java.htm)
3. SourceCode - [ServerHandshakeImpl.java](http://gitorious.org/ginger/libcore/blobs/d11a65b017fde8c4c997f41ee59e87e90d68b3f5/x-net/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse/ServerHandshakeImpl.java)
4. SourceCode Test - [ProtocolVersionTest.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/java/trunk/classlib/modules/x-net/src/test/impl/java/org/apache/harmony/xnet/tests/provider/jsse/ProtocolVersionTest.java)

Comment: thanks. So what settings do I need to change in order to define 2 ? Do I need to enable SSL 2.0, which I believe not recommended ?

Comment: 3.2 in fact is for TLSv1.1 (See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)). So, you should look for an implementation which supports this.

Comment: Thanks PCoder. It helped a lot. Since I am working with Software lib, which is black-box to me, I have no choice then alter my browser SSL settings.